# How to force ag-grid to take up rest of the page?

Tags: html, css, ag-grid

Currently the ag-grid I'm using is placed in a div, how I can maximize the ag-grid and the div containing the grid to take up the remainder of the page?

I currently have:

```
ag-grid {
    height: calc(100% - 75px);
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Does your programming environment allow selection custom element `ag-grid`, or is that supposed to be a class-based selector (`.ag-grid`)?

Answer (score 0):

Check and ensure your wrapper div takes the full space.

And you can use `height:100%` to make the ag-grid take full height of it.

Or you can use the flex way to make ag-grid to take full height;

```
<ag-grid-angular
    class="ag-theme-xxx height--100"
...>
```